# Handling flexbox children with Angular 2 Routes

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, router

I have a webpage built in Angular 2. The routes in the navbar are being handled through Angular's router. I have a `<main>` area where all the child components appear through each respective route which acts as a flexbox container. However, I want each flex-child/router component to have a different flex arrangement.

The problem is that I can't determine the organization of the flex-child until each particular `routerLink` is active. However, I can't style the child element's flex-position in its own component styles; you have to do that through the flex-container, in this case `<main>`. For example, consider this nav:

```
<ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                About
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li routerLink="/members">Members</li>
                    <li routerLink="/history">History</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li routerLink="/media">Media</li>
            <li routerLink="/merch">Merchandise</li>
            <li routerLink="/aaru">AARU</li>
</ul>
<main>
  This is where my ng-components go
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

This template is in my main component `AppComponent`. Let's say I want `/members` to be styled as `{ justify-content: center }` but `/merch` to be `{ justify-content: flex-start }`.

Is there a way in Angular I can specify the style/toggle css classes on `<main>` once I click the appropriate `routerLink`?

Comment: I can't see `home` in the code in your question. If this means `<main>` contains a `<router-outlet>` then please add it to your code. What if the children set a CSS class from within, can you use this to set flex-position from the outside?

Comment: edited. Not sure how I would do that from the template itself, can you clarify? what I really need is some sort of switch statement operating on the `main` element.

Comment: What would that switch statement do? Actually I don't really understand your problem/requirement.